# Linking AJAX with PHP code. Do i need to write it again?

Tags: ajax

I have a real problem. I have a php code and a form where when the form is submitted a POST request is sent and the page reloads again and ofcourse the post is viwed in the page.But i want to work with AJAX in order page not to be refreshed.I know the basics of AJAX but i don't want to  build all the project from the beggining.Is there a way in success function of AJAX to link to my php code??

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "index.php",
  datatype: "html",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(data) {
    //How can i link here to start running my php code which is located in the same page.
  }
});
```

Comment: Define "link to my php code."  This AJAX request will call `index.php` which can execute code server-side.  Then `data` will contain whatever the response is from that request.  What are you trying to do beyond this?

Comment: of course you'll need some major refactoring, but not all project, take a look at http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: on the net i have found examples only with alert messages.The problem is the php code is on the same page ajax is located.

Comment: do not put the code in the same script

Comment: well, "The problem is the php code is on the same page ajax is located."- that's not how web application's work, you need some more reading prior to implement what you want to achieve

Comment: i thought about it.It's a good idea but i didnt try it.Thanks

Comment: Eugen i know php very well but in building dynamic things i am not so good but i try to learn every day.I hope will achieve it.

Comment: @EugenHalca I wouldn't say that's not how web applications work - that's not how PHP applications work,  you actually can do that in other languages and frameworks

Comment: I could call index.cs/firstfunc , index.cs/secondfunc , ect. all from different ajax calls on the html page

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "somescript.php",
  datatype: "html",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(data) {
     // try this
     console.log(data);
     // see what 'data' actually is
  }
});
```

then check in the browser by hitting F12 to look at the console.

also are you sure you want datatype of `html` ?  you probably want a data type of json or XML ,  what is the server returning to you after the ajax post?

Comment: i tried and ajax works for me only with alert messages.Anything else is wrong.Maybe i will include my php code in an other script not embeeded on the same page with ajax

Comment: @openc this is not clear to me - is the problem that - the alert shows exactly what you want the ajax to return, then the page continues to refresh?  and you are trying to prevent that refresh?

Comment: i want to prevent refresh of the whole page.Maybe i need to understand better how requests in ajax work

Comment: you can't directly choose with js which function to call in PHP, you can only use PHP to grab the post value and call a function that way, so just change the url in the jquery code to another .php file that is just for handling this ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You have to cancel the form's submission so that the ajax request will take place, otherwise it is canceled. Also use `.serialize` to get a name-value pair string of the form data to use in the ajax call.

Html

```
<form id="MyForm">
  <button id="MyButtonId">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$("#MyForm").submit(function(e){
   //Prevents the form from being submitted
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data: $("#MyForm").serialize(),
     url: "somescript.php",
     datatype: "html",
     data: dataString,
     success: function(data) {
       alert(data);
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: and what can i achieve by canceling form submission??this is my goal to make a post appears asynchronously

Comment: @openc If the form submits it changes the page, thus canceling your ajax call.

Comment: that's what happens!But if i put an alert it shows the alert otherwise it refreshes page again

Comment: Which is why you use the e.preventDefault to prevent the page from being changed.